# Deploy angular universal (ng-toolkit/universal) on Linux VPS Apache Server

Tags: node.js, angular, apache, angular-universal, easyapache-4

After performing **ng build --prod** I got these files in my dist folder

[image]

1: browser folder

2: server folder

3: 1.js

4: server.js

When I Run node dist/server.js it works on localhost:4000 perfectly.

Now I want to deploy it on Linux VPS Server having CentOS, how can I deploy these files?

I did below steps:

1: Installed Node Js on my server using this link : https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Install+a+Node.js+Application

2: created a sample Hello World! NodeJS application on my sub-domain and its running fine Link : https://www.hoteljobber.com/nodejsapp/

3: hosted all my dist filse to my another subdomain for testing my app but i have fallowing Problems:

**Problem 1:** I have server.js file and its required app.js file for starting point some how I got this solution that I need to Create a custom startup file. ref: :https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Install+a+Node.js+Application

**Problem 2:** my server.js file is around 5 MB (even I build a sample/default angular 6 app). so is this my starter file i am confuse due to its big size

**Problem 3:** I made server.js is custom startup file but app is not working url link : https://www.hoteljobber.com/nodetest/

I can not understand what's wrong i am doing, what is the proper way to deploy angular ng-toolkit/universal project on Linux VPS server ?